# Why does Knockout.js's default equality comparer treat non-primitive types as not equal?

Tags: knockout.js

From the Knockout v2.1.0 debug source code:

```
ko.observable['fn'] = {
    "equalityComparer": function valuesArePrimitiveAndEqual(a, b) {
        var oldValueIsPrimitive = (a === null) || (typeof(a) in primitiveTypes);
        return oldValueIsPrimitive ? (a === b) : false;
    }
};
```

This seems unintuitive to me but there must be some reason Steve Sanderson went out of his way to define this.  Why would this be the case?  It seems to unnecessarily trigger change notifications.

Comment: great question!

maybe I just don't understand enough KO but, how does the above code trigger change notifications?

Answer (score 4):

This was done because if you have an observable that holds an object, Knockout does not know if sub-properties were changed or not.

At this point, we trigger a notification just in case one of the object's properties did change.

Comment: Wouldn't that only help in the case that an observable is set again with the same value?  E.g. if you have `var obj = {name: 'David'}; var x = ko.observable(obj);` Then you say `obj.name = 'Bob';` that wouldn't trigger a notification, only if you call `x(obj);` afterwards would it notify on a change correct?

Comment: Right, that is correct.  You can also call `x.valueHasMutated()`

Comment: That seems like a pretty limited use-case to me, and for me it's unexpected behavior that I had to look into the source code to understand.  Was this a issue that arose a lot in using KO?  It seems like normal equality check would only cause issues for people who don't understand how object equality works.

Comment: It is just indicating that Knockout cannot tell if your object has changed since the last time that it was bound and better notify subscribers.  In a complex application, there may even be cases of indirection where you don't even realize/care that you are actually setting an observable to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an observable, which is holding an object, you could make a custom equalityComparer, to return equality based on your needs. Just set the property on the observable instance you want to customize. The signature is:

```
myObservable["equalityComparer"] = function(a, b){ 
  return a===b;// Or any arbitrary comparison
};
```

Now your observable is only raising change-event, when function is returning false.