# Knockout's with construct forces an update of the entire html

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I've been struggeling with this for some time now and havent found a solution, hopefully you can help.

In my SPA app built with Knockout and durandal, i'm relying heavily on the With construct of knockoutJS. Something that is heavily embedded all through the core of both mine and durandals architectures.

Many actions come with their associated routes in order to store the previous action in browser history. Now an action is also likely to manipulate the DOM or trigger a CSS transition (e.g. setting a class on an inner div which starts a transition).

Unfortunatly, each time a with binding is re-evaluated, the entire DOM under that with statement is rebuilt thereby undoing my DOM changes and killing transitions. This is exactly what happens in my scenario which is something like the following pseudo:

```
<div data-bind="with: myViewModel">
    ... print current datetime ....
</div>
...
myViewModel(myViewModel());
```

Please see this jsfiddle for a more concrete example of this behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/k32Xf/

This issue is only with the with construct however i havent found a way around it other than by hacking in the durandal code itself. Is this a bug in knockout? what would be a suggested solution/workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything Durandal related in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thats right, the real problem imo is in knockout however durandal kinda forces you to use a certain architecture that triggers this problem. Basically i use a route redirect and the activation function of my viewmodel to take actions accordingly however this same route forces my HTML to be rebuilt.

Comment: Can you fork https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2 and create a fiddle of how you're using Durandal in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `myViewModel` observable changes, then indeed everything within the `with` will be rebuilt.  That's just the only way to make it work.

However, in your example jsFiddle, you are not actually changing the value of the observable.  You are just assigning the same view model again.  This unfortunately triggers the update, even when you probably expect it not to.

By default, a Knockout observable compares the new value with the previous value to decide whether it is different and should trigger updates.  It does this using an equalityComparer.  The default implementation will consider objects different, even if it is the same instance.

So, you may be able to solve your problem by providing a custom equalityComparer that uses reference equality.  This is as simple as:

```
myViewModel.equalityComparer = function (a, b) { return a === b; };
```

Here is a modified version of your jsFiddle showing this in practice: http://jsfiddle.net/CFhkT/1/

And here is more information about why they chose to implement equality for objects they way they did: [Why does Knockout.js's default equality comparer treat non-primitive types as not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714761/why-does-knockout-jss-default-equality-comparer-treat-non-primitive-types-as-no)

Comment: I see, thanks for this! I'll try and see if I can use this to as a solution